# Trying to figure out a portable data saving approach

Tags: c++, intel-edison

I have a program which is running on an intel Edison (32bit Yocto Linux).  It reads sensor data, and then writes that sensor data to a file.  The data comes in packets of 1 int and 13 doubles, with 100 packets arriving every second.  Some time later, I will be pulling files off of this and reading those files with a tool running on a x64 windows machine.

At the moment I am writing the data as a raw text file (as strings are nice and portable).  However, because of the amount of data that will be written for this, I'm looking for ways to save space.  However, I'm trying to figure out a way to do so that no data will be lost in the interpretation of this on the other side.

My initial idea was to go ahead and create a struct that looks like this:

```
struct dataStruct{
  char front;
  int a;
  double b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, l, m, n, o;
  char end;
}
```

and then do a union of this as follows:

```
union dataUnion{
  dataStruct d;
  char[110] c;
}
//110 was chosen because an int = 4 char, and a double = 8 char,
//so 13*8 = 104, and therefore d = 1 + 4 + 13*8 + 1 = 110
```

and then write the char array to a file.  However, a little bit of reading around tells me that an implementation like that might not necessarily be compatible between OS's (worse... it might work some of the time and not other times...).

So I am wondering - is there a portable way to save this data without just saving it as raw text?

Comment: any data format is portable if it's documented...  reading it then just becomes an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Probably better to do `char c[sizeof(dataStruct)] ;`

Comment: Also, the correct declaration is `Type variable[SIZE]`, not `Type[SIZE] variable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the others said: serialization is probably the best solution for your problem.

Since you are on a resource-constrained environment, I suggest using something like [MsgPack](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c). It's header only *(given a C++11 compiler)*, quite light, the format is simple and the C++ interface is nice. It even allows you to serialize user-defined types (i.e. classes/structs) very easily:

```
// adapted from https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c/blob/master/QUICKSTART-CPP.md

#include <msgpack.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct dataStruct {
    int a;
    double b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, l, m, n, oo;  // yes "oo", because "o" clashes with msgpack :/

    MSGPACK_DEFINE(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, l, m, n, oo);
};

int main(void) {
    std::vector<dataStruct> vec;
    // add some elements into vec...

    // you can serialize dataStruct directly
    msgpack::sbuffer sbuf;
    msgpack::pack(sbuf, vec);

    msgpack::unpacked msg;
    msgpack::unpack(&msg, sbuf.data(), sbuf.size());

    msgpack::object obj = msg.get();

    // you can convert object to dataStruct directly
    std::vector<dataStruct> rvec;
    obj.convert(&rvec);
}
```

As an alternative, you can check out Google's [FlatBuffers](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/). It seems quite resource-efficient, but I haven't tried it yet.

**EDIT**: Here's a complete example illustrating the whole serialization - file I/O - deserialization cycle:

```
// adapted from:
// https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c/blob/master/QUICKSTART-CPP.md
// https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c/wiki/v1_1_cpp_unpacker#msgpack-controls-a-buffer

#include <msgpack.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct dataStruct {
    int a;
    double b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, l, m, n, oo;  // yes "oo", because "o" clashes with msgpack :/

    MSGPACK_DEFINE(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, l, m, n, oo);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const dataStruct& ds)
{
    out << "[a:" << ds.a << " b:" << ds.b << " ... oo:" << ds.oo << "]";
    return out;
}

int main(void) {

    // serialize
    {
        // prepare the (buffered) output file
        std::ofstream ofs("log.bin");

        // prepare a data structure
        dataStruct ds;

        // fill in sample data
        ds.a  = 1;
        ds.b  = 1.11;
        ds.oo = 101;
        msgpack::pack(ofs, ds);
        cout << "serialized: " << ds << endl;

        ds.a  = 2;
        ds.b  = 2.22;
        ds.oo = 202;
        msgpack::pack(ofs, ds);
        cout << "serialized: " << ds << endl;

        // continuously receiving data
        //while ( /* data is being received... */ ) {
        //
        //    // initialize ds...
        //
        //    // serialize ds
        //    // You can use any classes that have the following member function:
        //    // https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c/wiki/v1_1_cpp_packer#buffer
        //    msgpack::pack(ofs, ds);
        //}
    }

    // deserialize
    {
        // The size may decided by receive performance, transmit layer's protocol and so on.

        // prepare the input file
        std::ifstream ifs("log.bin");
        std::streambuf* pbuf = ifs.rdbuf();

        const std::size_t try_read_size = 100;  // arbitrary number...
        msgpack::unpacker unp;
        dataStruct ds;

        // read data while there are still unprocessed bytes...
        while (pbuf->in_avail() > 0) {
            unp.reserve_buffer(try_read_size);
            // unp has at least try_read_size buffer on this point.

            // input is a kind of I/O library object.
            // read message to msgpack::unpacker's internal buffer directly.
            std::size_t actual_read_size = ifs.readsome(unp.buffer(), try_read_size);

            // tell msgpack::unpacker actual consumed size.
            unp.buffer_consumed(actual_read_size);

            msgpack::unpacked result;
            // Message pack data loop
            while(unp.next(result)) {
                msgpack::object obj(result.get());
                obj.convert(&ds);

                // use ds
                cout << "deserialized: " << ds << endl;
            }
            // All complete msgpack message is proccessed at this point,
            // then continue to read addtional message.
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
serialized: [a:1 b:1.11 ... oo:101]
serialized: [a:2 b:2.22 ... oo:202]
deserialized: [a:1 b:1.11 ... oo:101]
deserialized: [a:2 b:2.22 ... oo:202]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to serialize your data. And since I can assume boost is not an option, you would have to do it by hand.

True portability (expect for unsigned) it's a headache. However if you know that all systems that you use they all use the same encoding  (e.g. two's complement for signed integers and IEE754 for floating point), then you are in luck and you can do this using basic bit manipulations.

You would need to set the buffer byte by byte using masks.

The only thing you would have to do differently depends on the byte endianness of the machines.

Comment: sorry, I am too lazy right now to write code right now.

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel.  This is the sort of things that Google [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) were designed to solve - transmitting well defined data between computers in a manner that is not needed to be human readable. (EG as opposed to JSON or XML)

Alternatively you could go real old skool and read up on [ASN.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One)

And for completeness here is a [Comparison of data serialization formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data_serialization_formats), so feel free to pick your poison.

Comment: I'd give you +1 for protobufs, but then I'd have to take off  -1 for ASN.1 !!

Comment: @Alnitak Why no love for `ASN.1`?  It does exactly what the OP wants .. Not that I'd go there myself, but options are always good. (But I was being a bit facetious with the ASN.1 reference.  People just don't know their history)

Comment: I'm allergic to the ITU ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use serialization (ProtoBuf, Thrift, etc). But if you can't use it and need 'raw' solution the only way is to describe your structures using special types that have same size on all platforms:

```
struct dataStruct{
  uint32_t a;  // see cstdint.h or boost
  /// ...
}
```

You need to be careful with byte-order too. So you must always convert all fields to little-endian (or big-endian) whenever you are serializing it (passing it to the "other" side or saving to file).

One more thing to remember is structure packing )) See

```
#pragma pack(1)
```

or

```
__attribute__((packed))
```

It's a broad topic so easiest solution is to use serializers.

Answer (score -1):

I would tell you that text is safest.  Saving it as raw int and doubles opens you up to the big/little endian problem and potentially trouble with double layout formats.  Even going to text might cause problems if you don't delimit the various values from each other.

The alternative is to define a "universal" format of your own and translate to/from that in your write/read operations... perhaps output int as text but as pseudo scientific notation text say a 5 character mantissa value, an 'e' and a 2/3 character exponent.

Comment: You might tell him that, but you'd be wrong.   Without due care to ensure that every last bit of significant data is printed there's no guarantee that a `double` saved in ASCII will have exactly the same value when it's read back again.